# Dynamic input type angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Example - example-input-directive-production</title>        
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="inputExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <form name="myForm">
         <label>
           Is Bulk:
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isBulk" ng-change="onChange()"/>
        </label
        <label>
           Quantity:
           <input input-type="isBulk ? 'text' : 'number'" name="lastName"
                  ng-model="quantity"
                  ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10"
                  ng-disabled="isBulk"
           >
        </label>
      </form>
        <hr/>
        <div>isBulk:{{isBulk}}</div>
         <div>quantity: {{quantity}}</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
angular.module('inputExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.quantity = 0;
   $scope.isBulk = false;
   $scope.onChange = function(){
     if($scope.isBulk){
        $scope.quantity = "NOT APPLICABLE";
     }else{
        $scope.quantity = 0;
     }
   }
}])
.directive('inputType', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        quantity: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var inputType = scope.$eval(attr.inputType);
        console.log("inputType", inputType);
        element.attr("type", inputType);
      }
    };
});
```

How do I dynamically change input type based on a value.

Here is the plunker link

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/kmkNKPWcM5jq159k

Answer (score 0):

Use a different template with `ng-if`

```
<input ng-if="isBulk" input-type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="quantity"
       ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
<input ng-if="!isBulk" input-type="number" name="lastName" ng-model="quantity"
       ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
```

**Update**

You could add a watcher in your directive:

```
scope.$watch("inputType", function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
        element.attr("type", newValue);
    }
});
```

**Plunker :** https://next.plnkr.co/edit/EsTwRTChBHjDqD2e

Comment: actually it is working in plunker but in my actual code it is not working for some reason.

i am using same angular versions

Comment: Your plunker doesn't work for me. I updated my answer with using a watch instead of using a ng-if

Comment: i can type alphabets not working for me, i tried adding ur code snippet inside directive.

my requirement is wn i check isBulk = true and quantity = "NOT APPLICABLE" and wn i uncheck isBulk = false and quantity = 0. this is as usual but i should not be able to type alphabets if it is not checked. can u please update plunker link with ur working answer. thanks

Comment: if it is allowing me to type alphabets then input type is still text so it is not actually setting input type to number wn v toggle the checkbox

Comment: I added my plunker

Comment: i checked ur plunker first time it worked second time wn i check n uncheck for some reason wn it is checked "NOT APPLICABLE" string is not coming. 

still not working as i expected. can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the directive to watch the attribute expression:

```
app.directive('inputType', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶{̶
          ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶T̶y̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶=̶
      ̶}̶,̶ 
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {          
        ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶T̶y̶p̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶e̶v̶a̶l̶(̶a̶t̶t̶r̶.̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶T̶y̶p̶e̶)̶;̶
        scope.$watch(attrs.inputType, function(newValue) {
            var inputType = newValue;
            console.log("inputType", inputType);
            elem.attr("type", inputType);
        });
      }
    };
});
```

The directive will then update whenever the value of the expression changes.

**Note:** By having the watcher evaluate the attribute directly, the directive avoids using an isolate scope to evaluate the attribute.

Comment: i can still enter alphabets wn it is unchecked, still not working as i expected.

Comment: requirement:

When checkbox checked:

type = text
input val = "NOT APPLICABLE"

When checkbox unchecked:

type = number
input val = 0 

and input should only allow numbers